# Rails Devise - current_user is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

For some reason, `current_user` returns `nil` in my model-less controller (`Subscriptions`). I have found  nothing on the Internet to justify this behavior...

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    ...
  end

  def create
    current_user    # returns nil
  end
end
```

I have a csrf meta tag :

```
<meta content="xxx" name="csrf-token">
```

I can provide more code, but I'm not sure what would be useful.

**UPDATE**

So thanks to the comments/answers, I have pinpointed the problem to one particular action : `create`.

if I add `@user = current_user` to the `new`, I can show the current user's email in my `new` view. However, in my `create` controller, `current_user` returns `nil`.

I accessed the `create` action through a form (submit).

Before the form is submitted, I validate the input and then send a request to Stripe to get a token out of the form. If there are no errors (validation and stripe), I then send the form.

Could that be the cause?

**UPDATE 2**

In my error message, my session dump is **empty**, while it should contains the current_user info...

Comment: Is your model for users named `User`? because `current_***` will take the name of the model. What does `user_signed_in?` return?

Comment: It is set to false... That's weird because the user must be authenticated to see the page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turned out the AJAX request I was making didn't carry the CSRF token. For that reason, Rails was killing my session.

I added `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` in my `SubscriptionsController` and it is now working. It might not be the most secure solution, but it works for now, so I continue to develop and come back to this issue later.

Comment: Why wasn't it carrying  the token? I think I might have the same issue sometimes.

Comment: @am-rails, It's been few months and I don't remember exactly. It was definitely caused by my AJAX call though...

Answer (score 6):

Note that when you create forms using the `form_tag` helper, they do not automatically generate the hidden field which holds the token for CSRF authentication. I ran into this same issue with a form I had constructed using the `form_tag` which I sometimes prefer using.

I fixed the issue by including the following helpers within the form:

`<%= hidden_field_tag 'authenticity_token', form_authenticity_token %>`

It's basically a manual way of generating the hidden field you need for the CSRF stuff.

Answer (score 3):

for `current_user` to work you need to add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to your class, like:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController  
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    ...
  end

  def create
    curent_user    # returns nil
  end
end
```

and the `authenticate_user!` method will set the current user for you :)

Comment: I tried that before. It redirects the user to the login page, as if it was not logged in. I'll edit my question with more info on that in a minute.

Comment: Well, yes, `:authenticate_user!` what it does is check for `user_signed_in?` and if it's false, send the user to the sign-in page. It's not needed for `current_user` to be initialized.

Comment: The thing is, the user is **supposed** to be authenticated because he accessed the page. So, while `authenticate_user!` shows the problem, it does not directly solves it. Very useful to pinpoint the error, though.

Comment: Debug your issue: First, be sure you run exactly "create" action.. Second, just check out if your session is stable on any action: place somewhere in a view `<%= request.session_options[:id] %>`. It wouldn't change. So, if 1 and 2 passed, thus the problem is in app logic...

Comment: all before_filters [are deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L190-L193) in **Rails 5.0** and will be removed in **Rails 5.1**. Use before_action instead

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but I was editing the model. So everytime I updated the model suddenly that would happen:

```
current_model to nil
```

After analyzing things, it turns out that if you leave the password in the form, when the user tries to edit some attribute, the person is then forced to write a password.
Once the form is delivered and updated, Devise does the rational thing when someone updates a password, which is to destroy the session and ask the user to sign in again.

So that was why `current_model` was suddenly turning to nil. Hope this helps, have a great day!