# Getting an error in using current_user.email in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

I am trying to display the email of the logged in user in devise.

View:

```
<%= @user_email %>
```

Controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def dash
    @user = current_user.email
  end
end
```

Error:

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

I've followed the devise setup, and the rest of devise is working properly, so I'm not sure what is going on here. I also cannot get the current_user.id, current_user.admin?, etc.

*RAILS 4.1.1, Ruby 2.1.2p95*

Comment: See the following link for why `current_user` might be nil. Also, no point in assigning the user's email to an instance variable. Just use `current_user.email` in your view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423718/rails-devise-current-user-is-nil

Comment: You know, you're right. I don't know why I was taking that extra step to use an instance variable. Coding solo makes one do strange things...

Comment: Post your full controller. Make sure you have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to instantiate the current user. Also I assume your Devise model is actually User.

Comment: My model is really Associate. However, adding `before_filter :authenticate_associate!`, did the trick. I've lost nearly an hour on this one, I forgot to authenticate _one_ controller. This is what I get for not testing.

Comment: if your Devise model is associate, please keep in mind this impacts your helpers accordingly ie `current_user` should be `current_associate`

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind. I only changed it to user so that it would keep the common convention/use case. I've edited my question to show the entire controller, notice that it is missing the `before_filter`. 
Problem solved, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I noticed it never had an answer.

The problem here is that the controller did not have the before_filter as indicated in the devise documentation.

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Also, there is no reason to set @user to current_user.email, in fact that leads to lots of confusion when you get the @user variable in the view, since you would be expecting the whole object.